# Can we open two (or more) tex files in the same window in TeXShop?

Tags: editors, texshop

In TexStudio, one can open two or more tex files (or .bib, .aux, etc.) in the *same* window. But with my little experience with TeXShop so far, if I open a tex file and then a bib file, they open in separate widows. Is it possible to make all files to appear in the *same* window in TexShop as well?